# Highcharts bar charts: how to prevent missing values from taking up space

Tags: highcharts

I want to create a bar (a.k.a. column) chart with 5 distinct dates on the x axis. For each date, I want to display bars representing the health level of the top 3 healthiest horses in my stable on that date. However I have 20 horses, and the total number of different horses that are among the top 3 healthiest on at least one of the days can be 15 at most. Suppose for this chart, there are 9 distinct horses that will appear on at least one date on the chart.

The problem: highcharts draws the bars thin enough so that it could display all 9 horses on every date, even though only three appear for every date. This means that the bars are extremely thin, and there is a huge amount of whitespace. Not only that, but he actual bars are spaced irregularly because highcharts seems to be saving a particular space on each date for all 9 horses.

Is there any way that I can tell highcharts to not allocate space on the x axis for horses that I may want to display on another day, but don't want to display for the day in question?

Comment: As I understand, you want columns always positioned in the middle, no matter how many of them exists (1, 2, 3, .. or 9). Something like this is not supported, but you can create an idea [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general)

Answer (score 0):

It's all a matter of how you set your data up.
If you want to have a series for each horse, there's no way around the problem you are describing.

With a little different set up, however, you should be able to get a chart the way you want it.

Here's a quick example of one method to achieve it:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/W9fUF/

```
data: [
            {y:3, horse:'horse 1', color:'red'},    //date 1
            {y:3, horse:'horse 2', color:'yellow'}, //date 2
            {y:3, horse:'horse 3', color:'blue'},   //date 3
            {y:3, horse:'horse 4', color:'green'},  //date 4
            {y:3, horse:'horse 5', color:'orange'}, //daate 5
       ]
```